# Specify range of emmeans outputs to range of individual factor levels

Tags: r, list, ggplot2, emmeans

I am trying to create a figure using outputs from emmeans, plotting lines for 5 levels of a factor. I would like the range of each ribbon to correspond to the range of data on the x axis in which that level occurs, not across the whole x axis. i.e. some factors only had data at specific ranges of the x axis and I do not want to extrapolate beyond these ranges.

Current code that extrapolates across whole range is:

```
newdata=emmeans(model, ~x|factor, at=list(factor=levels(data$factor), x=seq(min(data$x), max(data$x), len=100)), type='response') %>% as.data.frame

figure=ggplot(data, aes(y=y, x=x, color=factor, fill=factor))+
  geom_ribbon(data=newdata, aes(x=x, y=response,ymin=lower.CL, ymax=upper.CL), alpha=0.3, colour = NA)+
   geom_line(data=newdata, aes(x=x, y=response))
   
figure
```

Answer (score 0):

I since found a bulky workaround:

```
#Build dataframes with max and min for each factor
factorvariable.1 <- c("factorvariable.1")
data.factorvariable.1=filter(data, factor %in% factorvariable.1)
factorvariable.1.range=range(data.factorvariable.1$x)%>% as.data.frame
factorvariable.1.range$factor=factorvariable.1
factorvariable.1.range$min.max=c('min','max')

factorvariable.2 <- c("factorvariable.2")
data.factorvariable.2=filter(data, factor %in% factorvariable.2)
factorvariable.2.range=range(data.factorvariable.2$x)%>% as.data.frame
factorvariable.2.range$factor=factorvariable.2
factorvariable.2.range$min.max=c('min','max')

Range=rbind(factorvariable.1.range,factorvariable.2.range)

Range <- spread(Range, min.max, .)
```

```
#filter emmeans data by max and min values
newdata=emmeans(model, ~x|factor, at=list(factor=levels(data$factor), x=seq(min(data$x), max(data$x), len=100)), type='response') %>% as.data.frame
newdata=merge(newdata, Range, by="factor")
newdata= newdata%>%filter(x>min)
newdata= newdata%>%filter(x<max)
newdata
```